# PHP array sorting associative array using a specific key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array which need to sort using a key value of "odbyx"

Here is the array **var_dump**

```
array(12) {
    ["id"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(1) "8"
        [1]=> string(1) "7"
        [2]=> string(1) "3"
        [3]=> string(1) "6"
        [4]=> string(1) "5"
        [5]=> string(1) "2"
        [6]=> string(1) "1"
    }
    ["subject"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(14) "ticke tick sbj"
        [1]=> string(13) "new tick test"
        [2]=> string(15) "fdsfdsfdsfdsfds"
        [3]=> string(12) "test subject"
        [4]=> string(4) "test"
        [5]=> string(4) "test"
        [6]=> string(12) "test subject"
    }
    ["msg"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(9) "test+tick"
        [1]=> string(4) "test"
        [2]=> string(9) "dfdsfdsfd"
        [3]=> string(12) "test+tcikets"
        [4]=> string(4) "test"
        [5]=> string(12) "test+message"
        [6]=> string(7) "tssssss"
    }
    ["department"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(10) "Technician"
        [1]=> string(5) "Admin"
        [2]=> string(5) "Admin"
        [3]=> string(10) "Technician"
        [4]=> string(10) "Technician"
        [5]=> string(5) "Admin"
        [6]=> string(5) "Admin"
    }
    ["priorety"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(3) "Low"
        [1]=> string(6) "Normal"
        [2]=> string(3) "Low"
        [3]=> string(3) "Low"
        [4]=> string(4) "High"
        [5]=> string(6) "Normal"
        [6]=> string(3) "Low"
    }
    ["status"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(4) "open"
        [1]=> string(8) "answered"
        [2]=> string(8) "answered"
        [3]=> string(4) "open"
        [4]=> string(4) "open"
        [5]=> string(4) "open"
        [6]=> string(6) "closed"
    }
    ["dateAded"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(19) "2017-10-01 12:34:56"
        [1]=> string(19) "2017-09-27 13:41:09"
        [2]=> string(19) "2017-09-17 13:53:04"
        [3]=> string(19) "2017-09-25 15:00:48"
        [4]=> string(19) "2017-09-23 10:41:24"
        [5]=> string(19) "2017-09-17 13:31:56"
        [6]=> string(19) "2017-09-17 12:37:22"
    }
    ["dateClosed"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        [1]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        [2]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        [3]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        [4]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        [5]=> string(19) "2017-09-30 13:41:09"
        [6]=> string(19) "2017-09-17 13:40:53"
    }
    ["dateActivity"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(19) "2017-10-01 12:34:56"
        [1]=> string(19) "2017-10-01 07:49:20"
        [2]=> string(19) "2017-09-26 10:35:36"
        [3]=> string(19) "2017-09-25 15:00:48"
        [4]=> string(19) "2017-09-23 10:41:24"
        [5]=> string(19) "2017-09-17 13:41:21"
        [6]=> string(19) "2017-09-17 13:40:53"
    }
    ["userId"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(1) "4"
        [1]=> string(1) "4"
        [2]=> string(1) "3"
        [3]=> string(1) "4"
        [4]=> string(1) "7"
        [5]=> string(1) "3"
        [6]=> string(1) "2"
    }
    ["res"]=> string(4) "true"
    ["odbyx"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> int(1)
        [1]=> int(2)
        [2]=> int(3)
        [3]=> int(2)
        [4]=> int(3)
        [5]=> int(3)
        [6]=> int(3)
    }
}
```

Logic behind the array

```
$array = array
        (
        "id" => $id,
        "subject" => $subject,
        "msg" => $msg,
        "department" => $department,
        "priorety" => $priorety,
        "status" => $status,
        "dateAded" => $dateAded,
        "dateClosed" => $dateClosed,
        "dateActivity" => $dateActivity,
        "userId" => $userId,
        "res" => $res,
        "odbyx"=>$odbyx
        );
```

I tried sort using below code but it seems not working

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'odbyx'), SORT_DESC, $array);
```

**odbyx** field hold a priority values (1,2,3).

i need to sort main array using that values, so i can display top priority fields at the beginning soo on a table

I want to sort the **$array** using "**odbyx**" **descending order**

**Example Output of id array, the other arrays also need to sort at once.**

```
["id"]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "6" [1]=> string(1) "5" [2]=> string(1) "4" [3]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "7" [5]=> string(1) "6" [6]=> string(1) "8" }
```

Comment: you're expected output ?

Comment: when order priorities order (3333221) the id array output should like this, the whole array need to sort
["id"]=> array(7) {
        [0]=> string(1) "6"
        [1]=> string(1) "5"
        [2]=> string(1) "4"
        [3]=> string(1) "3"
        [4]=> string(1) "7"
        [5]=> string(1) "6"
        [6]=> string(1) "8"
    }

Comment: can you update expected output in the question since it is not clear

Comment: @ArunKumaresh i added that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## proper use of [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

See also: [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

## your example is ***invalid***

Expected first entry in result: `0 => '6'`

#### Possible interpretation `odbyx-index == id-index`

Should indices in `odbyx` match to indices in `id`?

i.e.: `$array['id'][3]` should be sorted by `$array['odbyx'][3]`

If this is the case, then your provided code should either yield `0 => '8'` for the first index (odbyx 1 higher-priority than 3), or `0 => '1'` (3 is higher).

#### Possible interpretation `odbyx-index == id-value`

Should the index in `odbyx` match to the id ***values*** in `id`?

i.e.: The value of `$array['odbyx'][1]` determines the sort for `$array['id'][6] = '1'`

In this case, the result should be `0 => '2'`

None of these possible interpretations even match the very first result in your example. The lesson here is *specification*, i.e.: carefully define and describe the specific conditions required to solve your problem, on stackoverflow or anywhere else.

## Here's a place to start

Since the problem you are asking to be solved is complex, poorly defined, would require a significant amount of coding and testing, and has significant performance implications, I'll leave you with this tidbit of a solution to one of the impossible interpretations above. Good luck.

```
Class SimpleSorter
{
    private $orderBy;
    private $sortMe;

    public static function sortByIndexedOrderField(array $sortMe, array $byMe)
    {
        $sorter = new self($sortMe);
        return $sorter->applyIndexedOrder($byMe);
    }

    public function __construct(array $sortMe)
    {
        $this->sortMe = $sortMe;
    }

    public function applyIndexedOrder(array $byMe): array
    {
        $this->orderBy = $byMe;
        $keys = array_keys($this->sortMe);

        // sort, first by odbyx, then by value
        usort($keys, function($a,$b){
            $odbyx = 0;
            if (array_key_exists($a, $this->orderBy) && array_key_exists($b, $this->orderBy)) {
                $odbyx = $this->orderBy[$b] <=> $this->orderBy[$a];
            }

            if (0 !== $odbyx) {
                return $odbyx;
            }

            return $this->sortMe[$a] <=> $this->sortMe[$b];
        });

        // reorder by new key order
        $result = [];
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $result[$key] = $this->sortMe[$key];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}

$array = [];
$array["id"] = [
    0 => '8',
    1 => '7',
    2 => '3',
    3 => '6',
    4 => '5',
    5 => '2',
    6 => '1',
];
$array["odbyx"] = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 2,
    4 => 3,
    5 => 3,
    6 => 3,
];

$idsSorted = SimpleSorter::sortByIndexedOrderField($array["id"], $array["odbyx"]);

print_r($idsSorted);
```